# Adding lines of text using PDFsharp

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I am using PDFsharp to create PDF files. My problem is when I lay down the  lines of text to the PDF I get a single line only. So naturally, all of the text that fits on a the first line is visible since the other text has overflowed out of bounds. 
[image]

Please see my code below:

```
private void createPdf2()
        {
            var title = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy-hh-m-ss") + "-" + txtPlazaNumber.Text + "-" + txtLaneNumber.Text;
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine("Date: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")).AppendLine(Environment.NewLine);
            sb.AppendLine("Plaza Number: " + txtPlazaNumber.Text).AppendLine(Environment.NewLine);
            sb.AppendLine("Lane Number: " + txtLaneNumber.Text).AppendLine(Environment.NewLine);
            sb.AppendLine("RFID IP Address: " + txtRfidIpAddress.Text).AppendLine(Environment.NewLine);
            sb.AppendLine("RFID Port: " + nRfidPort.Text).AppendLine(Environment.NewLine);
            sb.AppendLine("TFI IP Address: " + txtTfiIpAddress.Text).AppendLine(Environment.NewLine);
            sb.AppendLine("QR Port: " + nQrPort.Text).AppendLine(Environment.NewLine);

            sb.AppendLine("Passed Tests").AppendLine();
            foreach(var p in passedList)
            {
                sb.AppendLine("\t").Append(p.Trim()).AppendLine();
            }
            sb.AppendLine("Failed Tests").AppendLine();
            foreach(var f in failedList)
            {
                sb.AppendLine("\f").Append(f.Trim()).AppendLine();
            }

            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument();
            pdf.Info.Title = title;
            PdfPage pdfPage = pdf.AddPage();
            XGraphics graph = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdfPage);
            XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 12, XFontStyle.Regular);
            graph.DrawString(sb.ToString(), font, XBrushes.Black, new XRect(0, 0, pdfPage.Width.Point, pdfPage.Height.Point), XStringFormats.TopLeft);
            string pdfFilename = title + ".pdf";
            pdf.Save(pdfFilename);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little bit trickier to work around. You need an XTextFormatter, a XRect for the region which is available for the layouter and then call DrawString(…) on the formatter instead of the XGraphics object:

```
var formatter = new XTextFormatter(pageGraphics);
var layoutRectangle = new XRect(10, 10, page.Width, page.Height);
formatter.DrawString("Hello\r\nWorld", arial, XBrushes.Black, layoutRectangle);
```

http://development.wellisolutions.de/generating-pdf-with-pdfsharp/

Comment: There is an enhanced version of XTextFormatter: https://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=9372#p9372 Consider using MigraDoc to take advantage of automatic linebreaks and automatic pagebreaks. http://www.pdfsharp.net/